# How to force webbrowser control to use different version of mshtml, shdocvw

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, browser, webbrowser-control

Does anyone know how to create an app similar to IETester tool .. I have IE9 installed in my system and I need to force the webbrowser control to use IE8 assemblies, that I have a local copy.

Any ideas??

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

It is technically possible, as outlined in this [MSDN Library article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375142%28VS.85%29.aspx).  Just create an empty file named app.exe.local where *app* is the .exe name of your main program.  You must copy all of the IE8 DLLs into the same folder.  Actually making this work strikes me as a bit of a headache, there are a *lot* of DLLs.  You can see them getting loaded in the Output window when you run a dummy app with a WebBrowser on a machine with IE8.  Project + Properties, Debug tab, tick "Enable unmanaged code debugging" to see the DLL paths.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the web browser control as you describe, however using the link in the previous answer you can use the .local mechanism or similar mechanism and directly accessing the COM object that WebBrowser wraps to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [new article by Rick Strahl](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version) which shows how to make some registry changes that will force the webBrowser control to use different versions of the rendering engine.